# Связь таблиц по двум полям

Tags: postgresql

Есть запрос

```
select 
emp.fio_name as receiver,
emp2.fio_name as accepter
from labs_archive_journal as aj
left join labs_lab_employee as emp on emp.id = aj.receiver_lab_employee_id
left join labs_lab_employee as emp2 on emp2.id = aj.accepter_lab_employee_id
```

который успешно работает. Вопрос, можно ли сократить кол-во джойнов до одного, не используя подзапросы?

Comment: только если в labs_lab_employee есть строгое деление на reciver и acceptor, которого там конечно же нет

Comment: Нормальный запрос. Я не знаю зачем вы его захотели сокращать. Поверьте, бывают такие страшные запросы, что можно вместо ужасов рассказывать